# How to list just the name of public repositories for a user using Octokit.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, octokit

Listing of public repository from octokit.I need the names of repositories only not the whole json

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

Model (Githubber) :

```
def self.octokit_user param
    @octokit_user = Octokit.user param  
    return @octokit_user
end
def self.octokit_user_repos
    if @octokit_user
        octokit_user_repo = @octokit_user.rels[:repos].get.data
    else
        octokit_user_repo = false
    end
    return octokit_user_repo
end
```

Controller (GithubbersController):

```
@githubber = Githubber.octokit_user('githubber_name')
@repos = Githubber.octokit_user_repos
```

View (Slim):

```
   - @repos.each do |repo|
       = repo.full_name
```